# Get Dom Element from jquery plugin extension

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to get the dom element from a jquery extension. This it let the user do the following

if i,

```
("#content").myPlugin.myMethod(myValue);
```

i would like to:

```
$.fn.myPlugin.myMethod = function (myValue) { $(this).html(myValue); }
```

this is basic example of what i'm trying to achieve. Though "this" is not the Dom element but the myPlugin function.

how can i access #content?

regards,

theHaggis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "standard" idiom is to use the [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method:

```
$.fn.myMethod = function(myValue) {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).html(myValue);
    });
};
```

This way, you can both support jQuery objects containing multiple elements and implement chaining at the same time.

Comment: the problem i'm having with this is : this = function() which is the $.fn.myPlugin function. and therefore isn't looping on the Dom elements.

Comment: Indeed, I did not notice you added an intermediate object after `$.fn`. I don't think jQuery is actually designed to support things like `myPlugin.myMethod` in the `$.fn` namespace. Is there any chance you can switch to the usual `$.fn.myMethod` structure?

Comment: i guess, maybe it shouldn't be an extension if i need to access the Dom elements. but i had a call from $.fn.myPlugin to $.fn.myPlugin.myMethod and thought it would be cool to all the users also just to call the method.

Comment: If you have a call from `$.fn.myPlugin()` to `$.fn.myPlugin.myMethod()`, you can use [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to relay the context. That way, the `this` keyword would refer to the same object in both functions.

Comment: yes i use this "$.fn.myPlugin.myMethod.call(this, myValue);" which works well from myPlugin. But if a call the method from outside the plugin i'm not getting the behaviour i'm after. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**Example 1**

To get the selector used in your plugin use:

```
this.selector
```

Example:

```
$.fn.myPluginMethod = function(myValue) {
    $(this.selector).html(myValue);
}

$("#content").myPluginMethod("Hello World");
```

Fiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nJeeH/

**Example 2**

The only other solution is to create a faux myPlugin method that just returns the jquery object to maintain chainability but this doesn't stop you from just doing `$("#content").myMethod("Hello World");` instead..

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function(myValue) {
    return this;
}

$.fn.myMethod = function(myValue) {
    this.each(function() {
        $(this).html(myValue);
    });
}

$("#content").myPlugin().myMethod("Hello World");
```

Fiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nJeeH/1/

Comment: Ex. 1: Bad idea. You are making jQuery match the elements twice, and in a plugin's context, `this` refers to a jQuery object already (e.g., `this.html(myValue)` is valid, and faster)

Comment: Keep in mind `this.selector` will break in jQuery 3.

Answer (score 0):

the function(your plugin) is assigned to `myMethod`, and `myMethod` is invoked by `myPlugin`, so when you execute

```
$("#content").myPlugin.myMethod(myValue);
```

the "this" keyword will be pointed to `myPlugin`.

you can see here for more information : [what does this refers to in javascript](http://www.lovecicy.com/this-in-js/)

you can put your method into your plugin, and provide a way to invoke it,like

```
$("#content").myPlugin('myMethod',parametersArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use closure and the bind() primitive ti modify the scope of the functions in JS :

> var myMethod = function (myValue) { $(this).html(myValue); }
>
> ```
> $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
>     var jq = this;
>     return {
>         myMethod : myMethod.bind(jq)
>     }
> }
> $("#content").myPlugin().myMethod('eh oh!');
> ```

Nb : it's easier to modify the scope of functions using closure than using prototype